# Run mongodb from remote server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and want to know about connecting to remote server. I have mongodb running on remote server. I want to access the mongo database from another server and perform all the operation. How can i do that. I am using node.js with mongodb. Please help me how can i establish the connection.

Comment: This should not be any different than connecting to a local mongodb (except for specifying host/port pair). What have you tried?

Comment: I have defined the following in config file `'mongodbhost':"username:password@ip_address:27017/test?auto_reconnect"`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, i am facing the same issue, but how can i add the authentication for that server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following library for node:
https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native

If you want a tool to access the database, you can use:
MongoHub (for Mac) & MongoVUE (for Windows)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks will this method update all my changes to mongo database

Comment: The library can be used for all CRUD operations.